# Conditional VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have two excel spreadsheets:

One has an id and a date
The other one has an id, two dates and a value

I am supposed to match the ids and return the value whenever the date in spreadsheet 1 is between the two dates in spreadsheet 2.

There is a one-to-one correspondance between those spreadsheets, and a default value of 0 if no match is found

The first spreasheet has a lot of lines. Would there be some sort of VLOOKUP function that I can use to get the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a very simple way to achieve that: concatenate the multiple fields you want to search, and you are done, provided they are unique. Otherwise you should look into array cells.

Answer (score 2):

SUMPRODUCT and array formula's are what you need.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$2000=A2),--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$2000<B2),--(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$2000>B2),--(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$2000))
```

this will have to be entered as an array formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. you will see excel surrond the formula with `{}` if you have entered it correctly.

Assumptions: ID to be checked in A2, Date to be checked in B2
Data on sheet 2 in the order `A` ID, `B` start date, `C` end date, and `D` value (numeric)

the array formula returns a list of true/false, which is then multiplied together. only if all criteria are `True` is a value returned (as any `False` answers equate to zero, and zero * another number is zero).

This will give incorrect answers if 2 ranges overlap

Comment: There should be a problem with this one though: The ids are not unique, meaning that in spreadsheet 2, you can have several ids (for different set of dates, hence the one-to-one correspondance). It seems to me that the VLOOPKUPs in the condition are going to stop at the first positive id...

Comment: If the ID's are not unique, then what would the correct answer be? Which value should it return: the first copy ID's or the second copy ID's? Depending on your answer to this question: One option would be to make all the ID's unique. - such as with a formula like this: =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,A1 & "-" & TEXT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1),"#"),A1) - then you would autofill that down.

Comment: Or if they actually do correspond by row, then you could just autofill 1,2,3,4 etc etc down a column and use those as your unique ID's.

Comment: hmm. I see that he wants to find every ID in sheet 2 that matches the one in sheet 1 (that's not a 1 to 1 correspondence), check the dates, and once he finds a date that matches, output the corresponding value, else output 0... This will take a little thought :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand his question but if I understand you correctly Sean you could try working it backwards - that is to say, put your custom vlookup formula on sheet two and then check sheet one to see if the corresponding ID's date is between the dates in columns B and C on sheet two.